# Extending of Symfony container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired

is it possible overwrite/extend `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::get()` method? I want automatic creating service, when it is not contain in container, but class of service exists.

For example:
Name of service is `My.MyBundle.Model.FooRepository`
Service with this name doesnt exists, but when i call:

```
$container->get('My.MyBundle.Model.FooRepository');
```

check class_exists for `\My\MyBundle\Model\FooRepository` and when its exists, add to container and return it. Dependencies of this new services will be resolve by `kutny/autowiring-bundle`.

This feature can be extended only for some namespaces or interfaces and in production enviroment can be cached, but for developing will be great helper.

Any idea?

Comment: why dont you use something like http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle so you have annotation in your services and so you dont have to maintain the services.yml. AFAIK the services in the DI container are only created when you actual call them.

Comment: Thx for tip to bundle, its useful. However my proposed solution use on another project and is very addictive for our team.

Comment: The Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel class has methods getContainerClass and getContainerBaseClass.  Might try messing around with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly answering your question but maybe it's answering your need: if you want to have "auto-wiring" inside your Symfony project, you can use PHP-DI inside Symfony. PHP-DI is an alternative container that can do auto-wiring (which Symfony does not).

Have a look at the [Symfony 2 integration documentation](http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/symfony2.html) to see if it can fit your bill.